# Unacked message if RabbitMQ server restarts in between the consumer consumes message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP and this is my connection factory code:

```java
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);<br/>
factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
```

During consuming the message if RabbitMQ server restarts or there is a connection lost I will get the below exception:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException: Auto recovery connection is not currently open

If server comes up my application will be connected again
but with a new connection and there will be an unacked messsage.
How to handle this? I want the message to be requeued and my old connection should be killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use the latest Spring AMQP `1.7.2` which turns off that:

```
connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
```

on the target `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` in favor of its own [recovery mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#auto-recovery).

Comment: But i want automatic recovery to happen but don't want the message to be in unacked state. Message should either acked or nacked in such scenarios

Comment: It will happen, but via Spring AMQP implementation. The framework takes care about those messages as well

Comment: Is this feature available in spring amqp1.6. If so how it can be configured.

Comment: ??? The `AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException` is there since version `1.7`. I don't understand why do you talk about `1.6`... And yes: auto-recovery is there in the RabbitMQ client since version `4.0`. The Spring AMQP `1.6` isn't compatible with that. But at the same time Spring AMQP auto-recovery is still there and works properly

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have a problem, that is if I have a RabbitMQ cluster with multiple nodes, and one of the nodes goes off, the connection aren't going to try to recover, but with `connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)` - it does (I debugged it - if recovery is turned off - nothing happens), why does it behave this way?

Comment: I would suggest to raise a fresh SI question with more info and against latest versions of products.